# Parse a number with commas in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin there is a shortcut for parsing an `Int` from a `String`:

```
"10".toInt()
```

However, if the number has a comma inside, e.g. `"1,000".toInt()`, it throws a `NumberFormatException`. I know I can use `NumberFormat` and `Locale` in Java to parse the number out. However, I wonder if there is a shortcut version for this in Kotlin.

Comment: Would 1,000 be an integer (1000) or a double (1.000) ?

Comment: There is no shortcut for this in Kotlin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following the [`NumberFormat` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/NumberFormat), you can use `NumberFormat` to parse strings as well:

```kotlin
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH) as DecimalFormat
println(numberFormat.parse("1,000"))

>>> 1000
```

There is no shortcut in Kotlin. You have to specify the locale somewhere in order for Kotlin to know what the `,` means. It could be either a thousand separator - as in English - or a decimal point, as in German:

```kotlin
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN) as DecimalFormat
println(numberFormat.parse("1,000"))

>>> 1
```